# Битрикс24 REST API - Server disconnected

Tags: python, битрикс24

Пытаюсь выгрузить список из 80К лидов из Битрикс24 через REST API. Использую на питоне библиотеку `fast_bitrix24` для автоматического ограничения скорости запросов.

```py
from fast_bitrix24 import Bitrix, slow
webhook = 'https://b24-nbdim2.bitrix24.ru/rest/1/tm14z6fs2e2x2lnc/'
b = Bitrix(webhook)
b.get_all('crm.lead.list')
```

Получаю ошибку `Server disconnected` или `500 Internal Server Error`.

При этом я знаю по своему опыту, что когда превышаешь разрешенную скорость запросов к серверу, он начинает отвечать ошибкой `503 Service unavailable`. И при такой ошибке снижение скорости запросов помогает.

А тут даже снижение скорости особо не помогает - скачивается начало списка и происходит вылет.

Кто-нибудь понимает, что на самом деле происходит и как это лечить?

Comment: Проблему видим. Возможно где-то в коде накосячено, тут принято проблему выкладывать с кодом или его частью.

Comment: ага, спасибо, добавил